# Problem while running Java RMI between 2 machines

Tags: java, java-8, rmi

I have two machines(OS - Ubuntu18.04). JVM(java version "1.8.0_66") is running on both machines, I want to call api running on machine2 from machine1 using rmi.
I am following link as - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html#4

But i am getting following error while running server code.

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
   java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: example.hello.Hello
   at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:420)
   at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:268)
   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$95(TCPTransport.java:683)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:276)
   at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:253)
   at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:379)
   at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
   at example.hello.Server.main(Server.java:23)
```

Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: example.hello.Hello
       at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:410)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:268)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$95(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: example.hello.Hello

```
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler$Loader.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:1207)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClassForName(LoaderHandler.java:1221)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyInterfaces(LoaderHandler.java:731)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:674)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:611)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:646)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:311)
at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(MarshalInputStream.java:255)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1559)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
```

I have done following steps.

1. mkdir 'destDir'.
2. javac -d destDir Hello.java Server.java Client.java
3. rmiregistry &
4. cd destDir
5. java -classpath /home/test/Desktop/rmi/destDir -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/home/test/Desktop/rmi/destDir/ example.hello.Server

But getting the error as above.

try to be more clear, i'm in lack of ideas in this problem, even it sounds like a classic :I have spend hours trying to play around with this but have got nowhere. Could someone help me find the missing piece?

Comment: Did you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071885/java-rmi-unmarshalexception-error-unmarshalling-arguments-nested-exception-is ?

Comment: Thankx for reply! I have already looked at this thread, but already in the link 'java.rmi.registry.Registry' has been started using 'LocateRegistry.createRegistry()'.I keep getting stuck on the same exception.I am getting this error while starting the server.

Comment: You're not compiling correctly. You should compile from the directory containing 'example', with `javac example/hello/*.java`, and run from the target directory containing 'example`, with `java ... example.hello.HelloServer`.

Comment: NB This isn't a problem running Java RMI between two machines. It is a problem starting your server program for the first time, and also applies to starting the client.